# How to increase logging from intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I am doing a large refactoring, IntelliJ IDEA 15 seems to hang.

How do I make it spew more logs so I can tell it is doing something and not hung?

Comment: Don't know about logging, but you could try getting thread dumps: http://inside-intellij.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-thread-dumps-to-analyze.html

Comment: You can use jstack on IntelliJ to see what it is doing.  Often when it takes a long time, it is either a bug or you are touching lots of files on a slow disk sub-system.  If this is the case, make sure you have lots of memory and a local SSD.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ IDEA does very little logging. The only way to make it spew more logs is to modify the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition source code and add more logging statements.

As the commenters correctly pointed out, a much better way to see what IntelliJ IDEA is doing is to capture its thread dump using jstack.